# Philippe Sarde's "Marie se retire de l'amour": style, inspiration?

Tags: baroque, renaissance

Regarding the number [Marie se retire de l'amour](https://youtu.be/5leY4brYNCM) that one can hear in the movie "La Princesse de Montpensier", can someone familiar with XVIth (XVth... ?) century music tell me what inspired Phillipe Sarde when writing this piece ?

Answer (score 1):

Philippe Sarde's music is modern but inspired by the secular music written around 1600 during the transition from the Renaissance to the Baroque era. It's particularly reminiscent of the madrigals of [Claudio Monteverdi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claudio_Monteverdi) (1567-1643). You can listen to some Book 7 of his madrigals [here](https://youtu.be/R5sIGgBuHtc). Another composer in a similar style is [Adriano Banchieri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adriano_Banchieri) (1568-1634) who developed a form called "madrigal comedy" which is a precursor of the opera form. You can listen to his work ["Festino nella sera del giovedì grasso avanti cena"](https://youtu.be/PXW1vv8hIh8).